# Angular code breaks if script not in html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this basic "insert data"
Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/Acts7/pen/qbgrjz
It works fine.
**But when I move that same script to an "app.js" file, it breaks.**

In my head tag I load this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And then this

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

So it can't be the order of loading.
And I know the script is working...

What am I doing wrong?

Googled it, searched it here.
This has to be answered somewhere but I must not be wording my search properly

Comment: check developer toolbar that it has any error? or does `app.js` loaded correctly.?

Comment: plz post console output.in chrome `Ctrl+shift+J`

Comment: It is an injector error.   And I read up on those in google but the examples were way over my head.`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- TestController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20TestController
minErr/<@http://localhost:8007/app/assets/js/vendor/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector`

Comment: Your reference to your `app.js` is not being resolved. Can you find it in chrome under `Sources`? Probably not. Check to make sure the path is correct using the HTML file as the start point (*relative from the .html because you did not have a ~ which denotes root of site*).

Comment: It appears to be there: [link]http://s15.postimg.org/56dhbtawr/chrome.png[/link]

Comment: Looks like your .css file can't be resolved either even though it shows as being there as well. Try moving the .js file next to the html file or placing them both in the root and updating the reference in the html file accordingly. This is nothing to do with angular, it is that your file cannot be loaded. If you are still not sure if it is your file being found or not then add a simple `console.log("found me")` to the top of your .js file as a test, it should come back in the console if it is read in.

Comment: the css indeed couldn't be resolved. that I did have incorrect reference to. But I wasn't worried about it as I didn't have any important styling at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*BEATING HEAD AGAINST DESK*

I forgot to turn off uglify js and mangle variables.

Okay well, good learning experience.
I will have to google how to avoid issues when minifying the script.

Comment: That is a common mistake. Use [injection names](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to get around it which should be the preferred way to write angular code.

Comment: use injection. when you inject a string, it tells uglify to NOT rename the dependencies.